# How to create dataframes from Amazon Ion file in Spark using python/scala?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to create a dataframe from an Amazon ion format file. But in spark I didn't find any format for ion type. So, I used json format to load ion file but it throws error. Is there a way or not for creating dataframe from an ion file.

I tried with below code

`val df = spark.read
    .format("json")
    .load("file:/home/mohan/Downloads/test_journal.ion")`

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer : No, at least not natively.
**[Ion](http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/)** is a proprietary format from Amazon, and it has parsers provided in C, java, JS, & Python. You need to tell Spark how to parse this format somehow.

You can build your own DataFrame by extending the API and following [this post](http://sparkdatasourceapi.blogspot.com/2016/10/spark-data-source-api-write-custom.html)